# Incorrect output for function which sums previous elements of a list

Tags: debugging, ocaml

Im writing code that is supposed to take a list as input,and return a new list as output where for each index, the values at that index are the sum of the previous elements of the inputed list.

This is what i got so far:

```
let counter1 = ref 0;;
let rec sumthingy = fun list ->
    match list with
    | [] -> []
    | [a] -> [a]
    | hd::tl -> if List.length list > !counter1
             then (counter1:=!counter1 + 1 ;
         [ (sum list !counter1 ) ] @ sumthingy list)
         else [];;

let total = ref 0;;
let counter = ref 0;;
let rec sum = fun list n ->
    match list with
    | [] -> !total
    | [a] ->  if !counter != n then
        (counter:= !counter + 1;
        total:= !total + a; 
        !total) else !total
    | hd::tl -> if !counter != n then
        (counter:= !counter + 1;
        total:= !total + hd; 
        sum tl n) else !total;;

sum [1;2;3] 1;;
sumthingy [1;2;3];;
```

The function "sum" works fine on its own so the issue must be in "sumthingy".

Expected output for [1;2;3] is [1;3;6] but i get [6;6;6] for some reason.

NOTE: I know the indexes of the counters are inaccurate . sum [1;2;3] 1 should output 3 but it outputs 1. It's not a big deal for me at the moment,i just want to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this expression:

```
[ (sum list !counter1 ) ] @ sumthingy list
```

Because you're writing imperative code (with side effects), the result depends on the order of evaluation of the left and right sides of `@`. But OCaml doesn't guarantee an evaluation order.

My guess would be that the order isn't what you're expecting.

You can guarantee an order using `let`:

```
let x = expr1 in
let y = expr2 in
x @ y
```

This guarantees that `expr1` is evaluated before `expr2`.

(An even better solution would be to write code without side effects :-)

Comment: Seems to help, however,now i just get the input list as output.
sumthingy [1;2;3] returns [1;2;3].

Comment: Try giving an input other than `[1;2;3]`. If I give `[2;3;4]` I see `[2;4;6]` as the result. So it's not just giving back the input.

Comment: Thank you :) you're always very helpful with ocaml stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're solving the task in a very complicated way. That is both not idiomatic and hard to read/debug.

I'd go with a straightforward solution first:

1. Implement a function that given a list and n returns a sum of lists' elements from 0 to nth
2. Feed the function from (1) to `map` and get the desired result.

Something like

```
let sum lst n =
  let rec aux lst s m =
    match lst, m with
    | [], _ -> s
    | hd::tl, 0 -> s+hd
    | hd::tl, _ -> aux tl (s+hd) (m-1)
  in
  aux lst 0 n
;;

let sumthingy lst =
  List.mapi (fun i _ -> sum lst i) lst
;;

utop # sumthingy [1;3;5;7];;
- : int list = [1; 4; 9; 16]
```

This solution is far from being optimal - it calculates the sum from the very beginning despite the fact that for each element we already have the sum of previous ones calculated, so ideally we need just 1 sum operation to get each next element. But it should be good enough as a starting point...